# Volume problem: Is my integral correct?

Tags: calculus

Let $R$ be the region bounded by the graphs of $y = \cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$ and $y=x^2 - 1$.  The region $R$ is the base of a solid.  For this solid, each cross section perpendicular to the $x$-axis is a semicircle. Find the volume of this solid.

My work:

Volume = $\pi \int_{-1}^1 \left[ \cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) - \left(x^2 -1 \right)\right]^2 \; \mathrm{d}x$

did I set up this integral correctly?

PS. I do have the answer sheet, but I don't want to peek at it just yet.

Comment: Do you have the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area of *semicircle*:

$$ \frac{1}{2}\pi r^2 $$

Comment: In other words, your work is almost correct, but look at the cross-section areas again....

Comment: so I should times 1/2 to my integral?

Comment: That's part of it yes....  Also, what is $r$ in your cross-section?

Comment: Could you draw a picture?  Does "cross section perpendicular to the x-axis" mean that I have to take half what I have inside the integral because I am rotating it around in a circle so I don't count twice the space?

Comment: I was imagining semi-circles with the diameter perpendicular to the plane, so I wasn't getting Shaun's  point either - in my image, the difference of the two functions was the radius of the semi-circle. I guess the key term I was missing was "base."

Comment: $\frac{pi}{2} \int_{-1}^1 \dfrac{\left[ \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) - \left(x^2 -1 \right)}{2}\right]^2 \; \mathrm{d}x$

Answer (score 3):

I made an acceptable plot of the area and the cross section perpendicular on $x-$axe. It was very good if I made it as M.S.E will but I hope you can do the rest by yourself. You know that $V=\int_{-1}^1 A(x)dx$ here and $A(x)$ is the area of selected semicircle below:

[image]

Comment: above and beyond is your graph!